# Countdown to Action

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I would like my application to do an action after a certain amount of time has elapsed (preferablely while the app isn't open or paused).

Example:

```
If(hours4 == elapsed){

    this.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. You have to start this task in background using `Service`. To make delay you can use AlarmManager. [Here is example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

or handler

> new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
>
> ```
>     public void run() {
>         Intent intent = new Intent("INTENT_WAKEUP_B");
>                         intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE",message);
>                         sendBroadcast(intent);
>     }
> }, timeToWait * 1000); // * 1000 if timeToWait is in seconds
> ```

Comment: If answear was helpful and solved your problem. Accept question

Answer (score 1):

Use AlarmManager to schedule events to run at a future time.